# How to scroll a list with arrow keys after clicked element is removed (Chrome)?

Tags: html, google-chrome, scroll

The scenario is like the following.

1. I have a scrollable list.
2. I click on an element of the list.
3. I use arrow keys to scroll the list.
4. While scrolling the list with arrow keys the clicked element is removed from DOM.
5. Scrolling stops though I want to continue, I am forced to click on another element of the list.

https://jsfiddle.net/b1a54tLf/3/ - click on the first element, scroll, after 3 seconds scrolling stops

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll;height: 2em;">
  <ul>
    <li onclick="setTimeout(() => $('#first').remove(), 3000)" id="first">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem applies to Chrome, with Firefox it works as expected.

I tried focusing and clicking the list dom element with javascript after the clicked element is removed but it does not work.

This behavior causes virtualized lists to be flawed on Chrome.

Comment: i also have the same problem.